# Insert numbers into an empty array

Tags: algorithm

Let’s say in example I have an array of length 5 which is filled with 0 ([0,0,0,0,0]), and I have to print all the ways that I can insert two numbers 5 in that array.
What would be the best way to do this efficiently?

Comment: In what language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate all [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of two indices from five indices (`nCr`, `C(5,2)`). Their number is equal to binomial coefficient `C(5,2) = 10`.

You can use `next_permutation` algorithm with set `(0,0,0,5,5)`  if available (in C++ `std::next_permutation`, or own implementation) to get needed arrangement themselves, or `itertools.combinations` from Python to get indices of 5's